# Displaying data from database on view using Laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get data from table Customers, Vouchers, and Bills, and display it on the views. Customer has a hasMany relationship with Bills and Vouchers. Here is my code for the models:

Customer:

```
    public function Bills(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Bill', 'customer', 'id');
}

public function Vouchers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Voucher', 'customer_name', 'id');
}
```

Here is my code for Vouchers model:

```
 public function Customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customers', 'id', 'customer_name');
}
```

Here is the code for the Bills model:

```
    public function Customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customers', 'id', 'customer');
}
```

Here is the Controller function i have made for this purpose:

```
public function client_search(Request $request){
    $date_from = $request['from-date-city'];
    $date_to = $request['to-date-city'];
    $client = $request['client'];

    $results = Customers::with('Bills', 'Vouchers')
        ->where('id', $client)->get();
    return view('pages.prints.ledger-report-clientwise')->with('results', $results);
}
```

And here is how i am trying to display in views:

```
@foreach($results as $result)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$result->Vouchers->date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$results->Vouchers->narration}}</td>
                        <td>{{$result->Vouchers->amount}}</td>
                        <td>{{$result->Bill->total_amount}}</td>
                        <td>{{$result->balance}}</td>

                    </tr>

                        @endforeach
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\Code\PHP\Code\CrownBillingSystem\resources\views\pages\prints\ledger-report-clientwise.blade.php)
in Collection.php (line 1661)
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(Exception), 1)
in PhpEngine.php (line 44)
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('D:\\Code\\PHP\\Code\\CrownBillingSystem\\storage\\framework\\views/f61b2b4b91bb544a7ee3c5532f7b257b0da1b8fb.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'results' => object(Collection)))
in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)
at CompilerEngine->get('D:\\Code\\PHP\\Code\\CrownBillingSystem\\resources\\views/pages/prints/ledger-report-clientwise.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'results' => object(Collection)))
in View.php (line 137)
at View->getContents()
in View.php (line 120)
at View->renderContents()
in View.php (line 85)
at View->render()
in Response.php (line 38)
at Response->setContent(object(View))
in Response.php (line 201)
at Response->__construct(object(View))
in Router.php (line 617)
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View))
in Router.php (line 574)
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php (line 41)
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 65)
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php (line 64)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)
at require_once('D:\\Code\\PHP\\Code\\CrownBillingSystem\\public\\index.php')
in server.php (line 21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's your problem. `Vouchers` is a `hasMany` relationship, meaning it will return a `Collection` object when called with `$result->Vouchers`, meaning that it's essentially an array and not a single object. If you want to access `$result->Vouchers->date`, you'll have to loop over each of the `Vouchers` and echo them one at a time, or use the first one:

```
@foreach($results as $result)
  @foreach($result->Vouchers AS $voucher)
  <span>The date is {{ $voucher->date }}</span>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The next problem is that you've got `<td>{{ $results->Vouchers->narration }}</td>`, which is the same problem as before; trying to access a property of a `Collection`, and not a single `$result` or `Voucher` object. (This looks to be a typo though)

You've got the right idea, but you need to know when you're accessing a `Collection` vs when you're accessing an `Object`, so read up on Laravel's Collections https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections and Eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Apparently the approach i was taking worked with a belongsTo relationship and i thought it would go the other way around as well.